# Q)While installing web3js getting some error.How to overcome from this?

Tags: web3js

Q)While installing web3js getting some error.How to overcome from this?

```
npm install web3-js

npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-08T17_58_45_678Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but perhaps you don't have git installed or it's not in your PATH.

Comment: what is the purpose of installing git?

Comment: can you explain me clear if you donn't mind